# Writing a Loop in Tableau that replaces NULL values for Pension values

Tags: loops, tableau-api

In Tableau Prep, I want to replace NULL values in the "JOB TYPE" column with "Retired" if that particular person has a "pension" in the "INCOME TYPE" column.

```
IF CONTAINS([JOB_TYPE], "NULL")= CONTAINS([INCOME_TYPE], "PENSION")
```

I know I have to continue with a "THEN" statement but I can't seem to get the syntax correct in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary calculated field:

```
IF ISNULL([job_type]) AND [income_type] = 'pension'
  THEN 'Retired'
ELSE [job_type]
END
```

Delete the original 'JOB TYPE' column
Rename new column as 'JOB TYPE'